# Delete item in listview by capturing checkbox selection in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I am using a custom list view that has a check box and button and populating the list view using cursor adapter.

Now I am trying to capture the checkbox selection in listview and delete the listview item using the checkbox selection.. After lot of web searching, I found out that Sparseboolean array will solve my purpose. So I have used to capture checked `checkbox` but array is returning null.

Below is the code:

```
public class stockmanager extends Activity{

    String getentry;
    private int storeID=0;
    //Database d;
    StockTable st;
    private String getstocks;
    public Cursor a1;
    Intent bd;
    Intent sd;
    //ListView popstocks;

    /*public stockmanager() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }*/

    static class ViewHolder {

        CheckBox cb;
        Button view1; 
    }


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockmanager);
        // d=new Database(getApplicationContext());
        st=new StockTable(getApplicationContext());
        final Button AddStock=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button DeleteStock=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final EditText entry=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final Button BroDetail=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        //final ListView popstocks=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final ListView popstocks =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final TextView displaystocks=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        final ViewHolder myviewholder1=new ViewHolder();
        myviewholder1.cb=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        displaystocks.setText("You have not added any stocks start by entering stock name and clicking ADD Stock button");
        getstocks="Select " + st.column1 + " as _id, " + st.column3 + " From "+ st.tablename;
        a1=Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(getstocks, null);
        if(a1.moveToNext())
        {
            displaystocks.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        poplist populatestocks=new poplist(getApplicationContext(),a1) ;
        popstocks.setAdapter(populatestocks);



        AddStock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                getentry=entry.getText().toString();

                System.out.println(getentry);

                Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().insert(st.tablename, null,st.insert(getentry));



                 System.out.println(getstocks);

                 a1=Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(getstocks, null);
                if(a1.moveToNext())
                {
                    displaystocks.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }


                poplist populatestocks=new poplist(getApplicationContext(),a1) ;
                //populatelist populatestocks=new populatelist();
                popstocks.setAdapter(populatestocks);


            }
        });

        /*  myviewholder1.cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Item Clicked");
                System.out.println(myviewholder1.cb.isChecked());

            }
        });*/

        BroDetail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                bd=new Intent(v.getContext(),BrokerageDetail.class);
                startActivity(bd);
            }
        });
        ******In below button i want to capture listview checkbox selection***************************
        DeleteStock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                SparseBooleanArray checkedItems=popstocks.getCheckedItemPositions();

                //System.out.println(checkedItems.valueAt(checkedItems.size()));
                System.out.println(popstocks.getCheckedItemPositions());
                //System.out.println(popstocks.isItemChecked(popstocks.getCheckedItemPosition()));
            }
        });




            }


    public class poplist extends CursorAdapter{

        public poplist(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        //StockTable st1=new StockTable(getApplicationContext());
        //Database d1=new Database(getApplicationContext());


        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ViewHolder myviewholder=new ViewHolder();
            myviewholder.cb=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            myviewholder.view1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1); 

            //if(c.moveToFirst()){

                //cb.setText(a1.getString(a1.getColumnIndex(st1.column2)));
                    //do{
                        //cb.setText(a1.getString(a1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(st.column2)));
            myviewholder.cb.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(st.column3)));
                //  }while (a1.moveToNext());

            //  }

            myviewholder.cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("Item Clicked");
                    System.out.println(myviewholder.cb.isChecked());

                }
            });

            myviewholder.view1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    sd=new Intent(v.getContext(),StockDetail.class);
                    sd.putExtra("StockName", myviewholder.cb.getText());
                    startActivity(sd);


                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stocklist, parent, false);
                    bindView(v, context, c);
                   return v;
//          return null;
        }


    }

    public void Declerations(){


    }


}
```

How can I solve this? Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Is your check box value is maintained as well.

Comment: do u need to complicate this thing or u need some thing much simpler??

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Amarnath I am newbie so I have choosen this way if there is anything much similar then I am ready to implement.. okease suggest.

Comment: @Harshit yes my check holds some value

Comment: check my answer to get checked values list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion , this is out of the context , and i dont know whether you are looking for this, You can just create a label or some other hidden field and , in you checkbox click event just append the text to the label 
for eg:

lblValues.text= lblValues.Text + chkbox.Text+"|";

and in the delete event

You can separate the string (ie lblvalues.text ) by using split or some other string processing methods since we have used a pipe symbol to separate each value , Your lblValues,Text will look like

"Val1|val2|"

and can assign that to an array and there you will have all checked values 
 if you are building a web app you can use javascript for the purpose which will improve your app's performance considerably and will avoid Postbacks so your clients can use this in a much convenient way. This is not the answer of what you have asked, but a simpler way to deal your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. I will give it a try but my issue here is I am unable to capture the checked value of checkbox that is used in listview... I can either get the checked value of checkbox individually or listview item check individually but I need something that provides me both in single function.

Comment: thats why i suggested you this way , since you are getting the values individually , you can append them to some string on click function .

Comment: To pick indivudally... If I got to list view item check then I am getting ID of the item I have checked when I go to checkbox then I am getting to check only `if checked or not` but in check box methods I can find the function that returns the text of the checkbox checked.